# Problema con un UPDATE de un SELECT en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

buenos dias. Vengo a solicitar ayuda. No logro ver que esta mal en esta sentencia.

```
UPDATE
    P
SET
    P.id_articulo = A.id_articulo
FROM
    articulos_x_proveedor AS P
    INNER JOIN articulos AS A
    ON A.codigo_interno = P.cod_proveedor
WHERE
    P.id_articulo = 0 AND P.papelera = 0 
AND A.papelera = 0 AND A.id_agenda = 2395
```

Al ejecutar el query me devuelve esto:

*Error Code : 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM
articulos_x_proveedor AS P
INNER JOIN articulos AS A
ON A.co' at line 5 (0 ms taken)*

Agradeceria la ayuda!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podrias hacer lo que buscas con una simple subconsulta directamente asignada a la columna:

```
UPDATE articulos_x_proveedor SET id_articulo = 
(SELECT A.id_articulo FROM articulos AS A WHERE A.codigo_interno = cod_proveedor 
AND A.papelera=0 AND A.id_agenda=2395)
WHERE id_articulo=0 AND papelera=0
```